# Application Getting java.net.SocketException: Socket closed randomly

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, networking, retrofit2

I am using retrofit for making network calls in my android application. Application is getting

> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed.

giving the stacktrace

> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:144)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:936)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:900)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:815)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:788)
> at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
> at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
> at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)
> at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:230)
> at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readHeaderLine(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:242)
> at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http1ExchangeCodec.java:213)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:115)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:94)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:43)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
> at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:225)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)

my retrofit configuration is:

```
httpClientBuilder
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .callTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)

return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(this.baseUrl) 
            .addConverterFactory(jacksonConverterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
```